# HTTP POST with URL parameters - what should the server reply with?

Tags: http, rest, jersey, restful-url

I'm working on designing a RESTFul service which provides CRUD operations for various domain objects. One such object is Person.

We have the following services:

```
GET /person/list?type=Infant
```

responds with all persons of the type Infant.

```
POST /person/list
```

accepts a list of persons in the payload and creates those records.

Question:
Does it make sense for

```
POST /person/list?type=Infant
```

in which case, we would create the persons passed in the payload and then respond with a list of all persons of the type Infant?

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not comfortable with this statement: "create the persons passed in the payload and then respond with a list of all persons of the type Infant". The two operations should be performed separately.

Comment: Thanks, care to elaborate? I'm trying to read up on the HTTP spec as well as the Atom Pub. I couldn't find anywhere explicitly forbidding this. What issues may I run into if I follow this approach?

Comment: You may not run into any issues but generally client initiates a request which the server processes and returns appropriate response. In the case of `POST /persons`, a new entry (person) should be created. In this case the resource name is not specified with the clinet's request, the new objects URL path would be returned to you. The new entry's ID is created by the server and is usually returned as a response to this POST operation. POST creates a child resource, so POST to /persons creates a resource that lives under the /persons resource, for example, /persons/sam

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it makes much sense for /person/list to be the api for adding a person.  If anything it should be /person/add.  There's nothing specific about REST that forbids you from trying to be clever, but the response I would expect on a /person/add would be the result of the add.  Trying to graft on some extra functionality just makes it more complicated for your clients (ie. the people who will be using your API).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with POSTing to /person/list to add a new person.  That is very common convention.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with it. However, I don't see any value to that approach, and REST certainly doesn't specify that convention be used.  For example, Flickr which has been around a long time uses this to upload a photo:   http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/.   Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: The problem with using URIs that have verbs in them is that it is not always obvious what the semantics of the request are.  For example, what does GET /person/add do?

Comment: I agree with Darrel. HTTP spec already provides verbs. URIs should contain nouns.

Comment: @Sam:  List is being used as a verb.